Let $f\in A$ and $p$ be the minimal prime containing $f$. If $\dim(A_p)=0$ then $f$ (and every element of $p$) is a zero divisor.
Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring. Let $f\in A$ be any element, and let $p\subset A$ be minimal among those primes containing $f$. If $\dim(A_p)=0$ then $f$ (and every element of $A$) is a zero-divisor. I believe this is a special case of Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem, but I can't seem to understand it. It makes sense that if $\dim(A_p)=0$ then there are no primes in $A$ contained in $p$, i.e. $p$ is the minimal prime of the whole ring. But how does this imply that every element of $p$ is a zero divisor?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

If $\dim (A_p)=0$, then the nilradical of $A_p$ is $pA_p$ (since there is only one prime ideal), so $f/1$ is nilpotent. What does that tell you about $f$?

$f/1$ is nilpotent means that $f/1 \cdot g/s =0$ for $g\in A, s\in A-p$, which means $f\cdot g=0$ so $f$ is nilpotent in $A$. Thank you for your comment.

If $dim(A_p)=0$ then the nilradical of $A_p$ is $pA_p$ because it is the only prime ideal (the nilradical is the intersection of all prime ideals). Then since $f\in p$ this means $f/1\in pA_p$ is nilpotent (since the nilradical is the set of all nilpotent elements in the ring), that is $(f/1)^n=0$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so $f$ is a zero divisor in $A$.
